# A random long is always the min value

Tags: java, random, long-integer

I write a function to generate a random long value between Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE, but it always return Long.MIN_VALUE, why ?

```
public static long randomLong() {
    return (long) (Math.random()*(Long.MAX_VALUE-Long.MIN_VALUE)+Long.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: What do you think it should return and why?

Comment: Numeric overflow in expression

Comment: How can I solve it ? A numeric overflow it's when a number is bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE ? didn't had that type of problem before, I need more informations

Comment: I think it should return a value between -9223372036854775808 and +9223372036854775807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your long value is overflowing. Because `Long.MIN_VALUE` is negative for a signed long, `Long.MAX_VALUE-Long.MIN_VALUE` is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` and therefore doesn't fit in the long during the intermediate computations.

Try using nextLong instead:

```
public static long randomLong() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    return ran.nextLong();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `Long.MAX_VALUE - Long.MIN_VALUE` is `-1` due to overflow.  That value is multiplied by `Math.random()`, a value between `0.0` inclusive and `1.0` exclusive.  It's a `double`, and `Long.MIN_VALUE` is added to a value between `-1.0` and `0.0`, the result is `Long.MIN_VALUE` still.  A `double` isn't precise enough to add something so small compared to `Long.MIN_VALUE`, so the result is `Long.MIN_VALUE` as a `double`.

To retrieve a uniformly distributed random `long`, use the `Random` class and its [method `nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong--).

```
// This Random object can be stored in the class for reuse
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Then:

```
return rnd.nextLong();
```